# It takes too long to send response (http status) back with sending emails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have REST controller, where I am updating DB and then I am sending emails to users. On the front end side, it takes too long to receive response status. How to fix that? Can I somehow send response status BEFORE sending emails?

```
    @PutMapping(value = "")
        @Secured({("ROLE_USER"),("ROLE_SUPERIOR"), ("ROLE_ADMIN")})
        public ResponseEntity updateApprovals(OAuth2Authentication auth, @RequestBody Approval approvals){
            String email = auth.getName();
            long userId = userService.getUserByEmail(email).get().getId();
            int approval = Integer.parseInt(approvals.getApproval());
            long doc_id = approvals.getDoc_id();

            documentService.updateSharing(userId, doc_id, approval); // DB inserting and sending emails

            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        }

@Override
    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a feature like sending email is better working in a separate thread. ex) `thread pool`, `message queue`, ...